# VBA Excel - Wrong values displayed in TextBoxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a ComboBox that lists customers, the user selects a customer and then clicks a CommandButton to display corresponding information about the customer. The data about the customer comes from 2 separate sheets, the ComboBox gets its list from 1 of the sheets.

Although both sheets have the same customers, some customers do not have a record in both sheets. The issue I am having is that when a customer is selected from the ComboBox, if there has been a customer in one of the sheets that is missing from the other, the wrong row of data is displayed in the TextBoxes.

```
Private Sub GoButton_Click()
'Finds ComboBox Value in RunDB, returns column 1 value
    NILWANo.Text = Range("RunDB!A2:U690").Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 1)
    RRank.Text = Range("RunDB!A2:U690").Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 2)
    CustClass.Text = Range("RunDB!A2:U690").Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 3)
    CalledDate.Text = Range("RunDB!A2:U690").Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 15)
    CustType.Text = Range("CustDB!A2:AA350").Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 3)

'Grabs Revenue data and formats in currency   
    RevLast3.Text = Range("CustDB!A2:AA350").Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 11)
        Me.RevLast3.Value = Format(Me.RevLast3.Value, "$#,##0.00")
    RevLast12.Text = Range("CustDB!A2:AA350").Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 12)
        Me.RevLast12.Value = Format(Me.RevLast12.Value, "$#,##0.00")

End Sub
```

I have tried changing the `Cells(CustProfileCombo.ListIndex + 1, 12)` to `+2`, and to `0`, but I still get the same issue. I am not good with VBA, not sure how to correct the code I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd need to use something like `Find(customerIdHere)` to locate the correct row on the second sheet

Comment: `wrong row of data` does not describe the problem that you are seeing. please describe what you are seeing in more detail.

Comment: the combobox finds a match in say row A20, but the textboxes display data from A19 for example. Or, if there have been multiple (say 5) customers that don't exist in the list, the textboxes might show A15's data. My assumption is it is an issue with the .ListIndex +1 part/s of my code. Although I don't know of another way to get the textboxes to display a value

Comment: Given not enough details on your structure, can only point directions. You should ensure the value in *CustProfileCombo* exists in the sheet you say has missing data. Can should use something like `WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("RunDB!A2:U690"), CustProfileCombo.Value, n, False)` where *n* is the n'th column from A:U. If there is an error (VLOOKUP failed to find exact match), then make the textboxes empty.